# CentOS equivalent of RHEL php-pecl-zip package?

Tags: centos5, php5, rhel5

I have a RHEL 5.5 host with PHP 5.1.6, and the php-pecl-zip package installed (using yum).  I have another host with CentOS 5.8 and PHP 5.1.6, and I want to have the same php-pecl-zip package installed.  When I search for php-pecl-zip with yum on the CentOS 5.8 host, no results are found.  What's the safest way to get this package installed?  I'm a novice at package management.

Comment: Have you tried the EPEL packages? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-enable-epel-repo/

Comment: @Eric, I followed the directions on the page you provided, and it worked.  Thanks -- if you submit as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. I have added it as an official answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric - I would recommend the EPEL packages - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-enable-epel-repo/

Answer (score 1):

Just type "pecl install zip". You will need pecl, gcc etc installed.
And I dont know the EPEL package, maybe is OK, maybe not.